# Trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 on Proxmox 7.4-3

Tags: 20.04, kernel, 22.04, proxmox

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 22.04-server on my Proxmox 7.4-3 machine. I've downloaded the ISO several times and checked the checksum, so I'm reasonably certain everything is fine with that. I've also noticed any 20.04 image I have running and working suddenly starts to kernel panic when it tries to boot after I use `do-release-upgrade` to upgrade it to 22.04.

Here's the error I'm getting:
[image: ubuntu error]

I'm kind of new to proxmox, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Are these settings helpful? What else can I provide that's helpful to solving this?
[image: settings1]
[image: settings2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer for this. I had to change the BIOS on proxmox to the UEFI bios option. Apparently that's become mandatory for 22.04. My ISO seems to boot and properly install now.